# query a specific url with AngularJS and Express

Tags: angularjs, rest, express

Inside my controller I have a call to fetch a document from my back end that looks like this:

```
orderFactory.query({_id: $stateParams.obj}).$promise.then(
function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.invoice = response[0].invoice;
    $scope.client = response[0].client;
    $scope.orderdetails = response[0].orderdetails;
},
function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.message = "Error: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;        
});
```

But the problem is that this code sends a `GET` request to `/orders&_id=5926bef0f5344c1ff8a9b295` but the REST end point it should access is `/orders/5926bef0f5344c1ff8a9b295`

The URL in the browser is `/trackdetails` and I cant use `$stateParams` to access the end point desired

So my question is there any way to access that end point from the controller? Or perhaps I have to rework my architecture?

Answer (score 0):

In resource:

```
$resource('your_url/:_id', 
  {
    _id: '@_id'
  }
)
```

In component:

```
orderFactory.get({_id: $stateParams.obj}, function(response) {
  // success
}, function(reject) {
  // error
})
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. these changes resulted in a `/orders` call, with out the _id parameter

Comment: Can you show your resource? Because, that's exactly what you need to assign into your resource. And you actually don't need to explicitly set $promise, because that's exactly what $resource returns.

Comment: `.factory('orderFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function ($resource, baseURL) {
    return $resource(baseURL + "orders/:id", null, {
        'update': {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}])` is my resource before changing anything

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. You're passing `null` instead of 
`{
    _id: '@_id'
  }`